# OpenGL version 2.0 rendering to texture

Tags: opengl, printing

I have to evaluate the possibility of modifying some 10 year old code to add a Print facility.  The code uses an OpenGL 2.0 context (not 2.0 ES, I mean the original OpenGL 2.0), so FBO isn't available.  The Print facility should ideally print to a much larger off-screen texture (as DPI is different between the screen and the Print DC in Windows).

Can anyone tell me if this is possible?  And if so, how I might go about doing it (which extensions to look at).

Comment: version 2.0 is not that old :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if the FBO extension is available. Even the oldest GPUs are capable of implementing FBOs, so you very likely have the FBO extension available. Or you use a PBuffer context, which is also very widely supported.